# Modify Email link in Sonarqube Email Notification

Tags: sonarqube

I have set up an Email notification in SonarQube for project builds
Everything is working fine but I need to change the following part

**See it in SonarQube: http://<>domain-name:9000/project/issues?id=attendance%3AAttendance%3Amaster&createdAt=2018-10-23T10%3A17%3A44%2B0000**

to

**See it in SonarQube: http://<>domain-name:9000/project/issues?id=attendance%3AAttendance%3Amaster** only

Can I modify that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot modify the URLs embedded in email notification messages. And in this particular example, the `createdAt` parameter is intentionally present to direct you to a page with filtered results so that you see only relevant content. In other words, this is explicitly by design, and it's not customizable.